# Accessing information about a variable that was declared before and changed in a function

Tags: javascript

So I have been building a fun text based javascript game, that relies heavily on OBP but I have come across a snag.  I will declare a variable but give it no data, then I will create a function that will add an previously created object into it's data.  The only problem is when I do that if I call the function it will not allow me to access the var's data.  Could somebody please show me what is wrong with this code?  Thank you so much and he is the code that I need help with:

```
function Monster (name,health,attack,def,moneycarry, crit, dodge){
    this.Name = name;
    this.Health = health;
    this.Attack = attack;
    this.Def = def;
    this.Gold=moneycarry;
    this.CritChance = crit;
    this.DodgeChance = dodge;
}

var SelectedMonster;

var Dragon = new Monster("Dragon",200,200,5,100,0.40,0,40);

var GoblinTheif = new Monster("Goblin Theif",130, 250, 0, 125,0.05,0.65);

var SkeletonT = new Monster ("Skeleton Tank", 210, 170, 30, 100, 0.3, 0.00)

function MonsterSummon(){
    var MonsterSelector = Math.random();

    if(MonsterSelector < 0.360 && MonsterSelector > 0){
        var SelectedMonster = Dragon;
    }
    else if(MonsterSelector < 0.70 && MonsterSelector > 0.35){
        var SelectedMonster = GoblinTheif;
    }
    else if(MonsterSelector >= 0.70){
        var SelectedMonster = SkeletonT
    }
}
MonsterSummon()
console.log(SelectedMonster.name);`
```

Sorry about the sloppy formating I have no earthly idea how to make the code that i wrote stay in the codeblocks that stackoverflow provides so, Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare 'SelectedMonster' as a global variable and then within MonsterSummon you create a separate local variable 'SelectedMonster'. If you remove the var in the MonsterSummon function you then assign the value to the global variable.

Your best to stay clear of global variable for issues like this.

Also, it should be console.log(SelectedMonster.Name);

Answer (score 0):

You're redefining the `SelectedMonster` variable.

Try:

```
function MonsterSummon(){
    var MonsterSelector = Math.random();

    if(MonsterSelector < 0.360 && MonsterSelector > 0){
        SelectedMonster = Dragon;
    }
    else if(MonsterSelector < 0.70 && MonsterSelector > 0.35){
        SelectedMonster = GoblinTheif;
    }
    else if(MonsterSelector >= 0.70){
        SelectedMonster = SkeletonT
    }
}
```